# Count occurrence of a values with time complexity of O(log n)

Tags: python, time-complexity

Given a **sorted** list L of integers (lowest value at the start), **different** from each other, return how many times L[i] == i for i>=0.

```
>>> count_occur([-5,-2,0,3,8])
1
>>> count_occur([-5,-2,2,3,8])
2
>>> count_occur([-5,-2,0,4,8])
0
```

The thing is I should implement it with time complexity of O(logn) on the **Worst Case**.

I can implement it for O(logn) on and average case, but apparently it's not good enough.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your average case solution for `O(log n)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dificulty solving a code in O(logn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148557/dificulty-solving-a-code-in-ologn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L[i] == i` can only be true for a contiguous range of values of `i`. (Can you see why?) Thus, we can solve this problem in O(log(n)) worst-case time by binary searching for the leftmost and rightmost values for which `L[i] - i == 0`.

Using the `bisect` module for the binary searches:

```
import bisect

class HelperList(object):
    """Lazily computes l[i] - i to determine values."""
    def __init__(self, l):
        super(HelperList, self).__init__()
        self.l = l
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.l[i] - i

def count_occur(l):
    helperlist = HelperList(l)
    leftmost = bisect.bisect_left(helperlist, 0)
    if l[leftmost] != leftmost:
        return 0
    return bisect.bisect_right(helperlist, 0) - leftmost
```